# Linq query low performance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, optimization

I have the following code in C#,using Entity Framework:

```
using (var db = new RespDB())
                {
                    var result = (from proj in db.ProjectModels
                                  where proj.Name.Equals(project.Name)
                                  where proj.Platform.Equals(project.Platform)
                                  where proj.Variant.Equals(project.Variant)
                                  where proj.MY == project.MY
                                  where proj.Controller.Equals(project.Controller)
                                  select proj).FirstOrDefault();
               }
```

In the code, "project" is a object.
The problem is that the database is big and this piece of code is very slow, using Visual Studio performance analysis I saw that the problem is at "firstordefault" method and at "where".
Is there a way to optimize this code ?

Comment: Write the query in SQL and run it in SSMS to compare. That's a lot of `WHERE`s and I doubt you have all those columns covered by indexes.

Comment: EF performance is DB performance. Don‘t check the performance in C#, check the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

In the Entity Model you should have a Key or Unique Index properties.  So this query should be either

```
var result = (from proj in db.ProjectModels
              where proj.ID == project.ID
              select proj).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var result = (from proj in db.ProjectModels
              where proj.Name == project.Name
                 && proj.Platform == project.Platform
                 && proj.Variant == project.Variant
              select proj).FirstOrDefault();
```

If (Name,Platform,Variant) either is the Entity Key or has a Unique Index.

Comment: I can't do the first one because that's what i want to find with my code, the ideea of that code is to find the id of some project, i wanted to check if that project entity exists.

Comment: So you need a Unique Index on the non-key properties that define what an "existing" project is.